# I created an android wear app, the code compiles correctly but in the emulator it keeps stopping, what's causing it?

Tags: java, android

Here is the java, it lists no errors when running, I am trying to make the text change every 5 seconds, however app keeps closing and wants me to reopen it.

```
 package cross.and.sword.ptsdp;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
  import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

```
private TextView mTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelText);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    // Enables Always-on
    setAmbientEnabled();

    final TextView textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelText);

    Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            boolean processing = true;
            int number_processed=0;
            do {
                mTextView.setText("Text 1");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    if (++number_processed>6)
                        processing=false;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace( );
                } finally {
                    mTextView.setText("Text 2");
                }
            } while(processing);
            mTextView.setText("Text3");

            }

    };


    };
}
```

11/28 18:47:36: Launching MainActivity
$ adb install-multiple -r -t C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\debug\resources-debug.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\Howard\AndroidStudioProjects\PTSDP\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed in 10 s 353 ms
$ adb shell am start -n "cross.and.sword.ptsdp/cross.and.sword.ptsdp.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2497 on device Android_Wear_Round_API_26 [emulator-5554]
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: cross.and.sword.ptsdp, PID: 2497
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cross.and.sword.ptsdp/cross.and.sword.ptsdp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2718)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2563)
        at cross.and.sword.ptsdp.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:9)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: where is your stacktrace?

Comment: I have just updated it with the what I believe is the stacktrace.

Comment: It's a NullPointerException.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/24347569/139985

Comment: How do I fix it?

Comment: fix the formatting pls

Comment: 2 issues I can see, 1: private TextView mTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WelText); is outside of onCreate, findviewbyid should not be called anywhere context may be null. 2: when you update your text view inside the thread, you cannot update a view outside of the UI thread, you should call runOnUiThread(new Runnable().....)